# how to extension which have different context can communicate each other?

Tags: asterisk

sip.conf

```
[101]
context = technical-office
[102]
context = employment-department
```

extension.conf

```
[technical-office]
exten => 101,1,answer()
exten => 101,2,dial(sip/101)
exten => 101,3,hangup()

[employment-department]
exten => 102,1,answer()
exten => 102,2,dial(sip/102)
exten => 102,3,hangup()
```

When i use '101' extension to dial '102', i have an error "no routing to destionation". But contexts are on the same is has no error

Answer (score 6):

That's because you dont have the right context.
SIP peer 101 points to context technical-office and you dont have extension 102 in that context.
To get it works use:

sip.conf

```
    [101]
    context = technical-office
    [102]
    context = technical-office
```

extension.conf

```
    [technical-office]
    exten => _1XX,1,answer()
    exten => _1XX,n,dial(sip/${EXTEN})
    exten => _1XX,n,hangup()
```

Which both phone are in the same context, so if 101 dial 102, it going to work and if 102 going to dial 101, its going to work as well.
In fact _1XX is called a pattern and ${EXTEN} is to refer to the extension that you dialed.
It's really common in Asterisk dialplan.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can dial from one context to the next one.

sip.conf:

```
[101]
context = technical-office
[102]
context = employment-department
```

extensions.conf:

```
[technical-office]
include => dial-context

[employment-department]
include => dial-context

[dial-context]
exten => _1XX,1,answer()
exten => _1XX,n,dial(sip/${EXTEN})
exten => _1XX,n,hangup()
```

Your example is not working because the exten => XXX means the dialed phone, not the from phone. Your example will work if you exchange on your dialplan (extensions.conf) 101 by 102, allowing extensions on context A to call to extenion 102 and doing the same on the other way.

Check on [voip-info](http://www.voip-info.org/) or look for the [Asterisk: The future of telephony (O'Reilly)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009625.do) book to a complete introduction to Asterisk.

Hope it helps